# If string x is conjugate to string y, how can you prove that the reverse of x is conjugate to the reverse of y?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, proof-techniques, strings

I am relatively new to writing proofs and I am stuck trying to prove that if $x$ ~ $y$, then $x^R$ ~ $y^R$. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What definition are you using? For most definitions, this is rather straightforward, so I suggest spending more time on it. It is possible that your main issue is that you don't understand the definition.

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.